# Material Table Add Row position

Tags: reactjs, material-table

When we click Add Row in material table , the  "new edit row" appears at the bottom of the table.
This is an issue when you have more rows per page, user has to scroll every time to add  anything.

I want "Edit Row" to appear at top instead of bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `addRowPoistion` option to `first`, like this:

```
  <MaterialTable
        columns={tableColumns}
        data={data}
        title="Material Table - Add Row Position "
        options={{
          addRowPosition: "first",
          search: false,
          actionsColumnIndex: -1,
        }}
    ...
    />
```

Full sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-editable-password-field-forked-ifq9w?file=/src/App.js).